# UIButton Custom Type with background color and transparent foreground image not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have the following custom button:

```
    _button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    _button.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_bg_highlighted.png"];
    [_button setBackgroundImage:bg forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

As expected, the button has a dark gray background. When I press the button, the background image is shown (red square).

Later in the program I'm setting the buttons foreground image, which is transparent (red rectangle). After that the gray background changes to white. When I press the button, it becomes gray.

When I'm setting the image right after `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` it works great.

[image]

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Just in case anyone else has the problem I did and lands here, `button.highlighted = YES;` on my Custom button was altering the color of my button image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm stupid. I'm getting the image from a `NSData` object. At the server the `UIImage` is converted to `NSData` with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, quality)`. But this should be `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`, otherwise the transparency gets lost at the client. Now everything works great!